# How to sync lifecycle_rule of s3 bucket actual configuration with terraform script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

The rule was set up manually in AWS console. I wanted to sync it in my terraform script.

I have the following defined in terraform script:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucketname" {
  bucket = "${local.bucket_name}"
  acl = "private"
  force_destroy = "false"
  acceleration_status = "Enabled"

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true,
    transition {
      days = 30
      storage_class = "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true,
    expiration {
      days = 30
    }
  }

}
```

However this always gives me the following output when applying it:

```
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.1300905083.date:          "" => ""
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.1300905083.days:          "" => "30"
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.1300905083.storage_class: "" => "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.3021102259.date:          "" => ""
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.3021102259.days:          "0" => "0"
 lifecycle_rule.0.transition.3021102259.storage_class: "INTELLIGENT_TIERING" => ""
```

I'm not sure what's the behavior , is it trying to delete the existing and recreate it?

Answer (score 1):

> is it trying to delete the existing and recreate it?

Yes. If the rules have been created outside of TF, as far as TF is concerned, they don't exist. Thus TF is going to replace existing ones, as it is not aware of them. [TF docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html#currently-state-only) states:

> It [TF] does not generate configuration.

Since your bucket does not have lifecycles in TF, TF treats them as non-existent.

When you are managing your infrastructure using any IoC tool (TF, CloudFormation, ...) its a **bad practice** to modify resources "manually", outside of these tools. This leads to, so called, [resource drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html) which in turn can lead to more issues in future.

In your case, you either have to re-create the rules in TF, which means the manually ones will be replaced, or [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) them. However, you can't import individual attributes of a resource. Thus you would have to import the bucket.

Comment: thanks for your input! yeah i noticed this is the behavior for some resources. But, usually there's a warning, it would say it explicity that the resource would be destroyed and created. For this one it seems that it's just updating it and creating a new one which makes sense because i made a mistake in the config. Noted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like i just made a silly mistake putting a value for the days parameter. The correct config which is same as the manual update done is:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucketname" {
  bucket = "${local.bucket_name}"
  acl = "private"
  force_destroy = "false"
  acceleration_status = "Enabled"

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true,
    transition {
      storage_class = "INTELLIGENT_TIERING"
    }
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true,
    expiration {
      days = 30
    }
  }

}
```